# How to get selector on which 'click' event has been bound?

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery `on` function to bind click event:

```
$('#page-container, .some-class').on('click', '.do-something', function(event) {
    // #page-container or .some-class?
});
```

Now inside callback function I want to know if 'click' event has been fired from `#page-container` or `.some-class`. With `$(this)` I get only selector which has been clicked.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`delagateTarget` property of the `event` object refers to the target of delegation:

```
$('#page-container, .some-class').on('click', '.do-something', function(event) {
    var dt = event.delegateTarget;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SmXCG/

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted, simple and without additional DOM searching. Brilliant.

Answer (score 3):

try something like this

```
    $('#page-container, .some-class').on('click', '.do-something', function(event) {
        $(this).attr('id'); // #page-container 

        $(this).hasClass('.some-class'); //Will return true if it has some-class
    });
```

Comment: `this` refers to `.do-something` element.

Comment: It works but without the period for class specification (i.e., `some-class`, not `.some-class`). This was useful for me. Thanks @ rajeshkakawat

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
$('#page-container, .some-class').on('click', '.do-something', function (event) {
    if ($(this).closest('#page-container').length) 
        alert('Its #page-container');
    else if ($(this).closest('.some-class').length) 
        alert('Its .some-class');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('#page-container, .some-class').on('click', '.do-something', function(event) {
    var isSomeClass = $(this).closest('.some-class').length > 0
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/EcWv5/)

Answer (score 0):

Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/ZV9aE/)**

Try this

```
$('#page-container, .some-class').on('click', function(event) {
alert($(this).text());
});
```