# Call / Trigger all functions (bind event handlers) Programatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures, jquery-events

I have a Javascript file which contains bind events. Each bind event is on a different element / selector.

I need to be able to go through each bind event, identify the selector (perhaps with event.delegateTarget - [How to get selector on which 'click' event has been bound?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18611580/how-to-get-selector-on-which-click-event-has-been-bound))

Then trigger the corresponding bind event.

```
$('body').on('click', '.element-selector', function() {
  // DO ACTION HERE
});


$('.element-selector').change(function() {
   // DO ACTION HERE
});
```

I guess this would involve:

1. Being able to loop through all functions / bind events
2. Find the selector
3. Trigger the corresponding jQuery bind event on that selector

How would I approach this problem ?

It is tricky because, I can't use `$('.element-selector').trigger('click')` because the selectors are dynamic, and the bind events are also dynamic. Also some functions are set up using event delegation , and some are not. I tried to illustrate that with the examples I showed above.

Comment: What is your [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)? Is this for a testing framework of some kind? "*I want to go through this js file*" is a pretty weird requirement otherwise.

Comment: Yes that is correct, I have a javascript file which contains bind events. Each bind event is on a different element / selector.

I need to be able to go through each bind event, identify the selector (perhaps with event.delegateTarget - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18611580/how-to-get-selector-on-which-click-event-has-been-bound)

Then trigger the corresponding bind event. 

Does that help to clarify the problem ?

Comment: Would an acceptable solution involve redefining `$` to intercept the event listeners before executing the file?

Answer (score 0):

This solution depends on the attachment point.  For ease of demonstration I used the `'*'` selector to get everything (not so good for most things)

**Warning: this uses undocumented functionality**

Related [jQuery find events handlers registered with an object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2518421/125981)

IF you want to target specific selectors you can do that instead. i.e. `'body'`, your class selector etc.

Results of clicking the button here is:

```
checking...
type: object
{
  "click": [
    {
      "type": "click",
      "origType": "click",
      "data": undefined,
      "handler": function () {
  // DO ACTION HERE
  console.log("got click");
},
      "guid": 2,
      "selector": ".element-selector",
      "needsContext": false,
      "namespace": ""
    }
  ]
}
type: object
{
  "custom": [
    {
      "type": "custom",
      "origType": "custom",
      "data": undefined,
      "handler": function () {
  // DO ACTION HERE
  console.log("got change");
},
      "guid": 4,
      "selector": undefined,
      "needsContext": undefined,
      "namespace": ""
    }
  ]
}
type: object
{
  "change": [
    {
      "type": "change",
      "origType": "change",
      "data": undefined,
      "handler": function () {
  // DO ACTION HERE
  console.log("got change");
},
      "guid": 6,
      "selector": undefined,
      "needsContext": undefined,
      "namespace": ""
    }
  ]
}
type: object
{
  "click": [
    {
      "type": "click",
      "origType": "click",
      "data": undefined,
      "handler": function checkme() {
  console.log('checking...');
  $('*').each(function(index, element) {
    var evts = $._data(element, "events");
    if (typeof evts === "object") {
      console.log("type:", typeof evts);
      console.log(evts);
    }
  });
},
      "guid": 8,
      "selector": undefined,
      "needsContext": undefined,
      "namespace": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

```js
$('body').on('click', '.element-selector', function() {
  // DO ACTION HERE
  console.log("got click");
});
$('.element-selector').on('custom', function() {
  // DO ACTION HERE
  console.log("got custom");
});

$('.input-element-selector').on('change', function() {
  // DO ACTION HERE
  console.log("got change");
});

function checkme() {
  console.log('checking...');
  $('*').each(function(index, element) {
    var evts = $._data(element, "events");
    if (typeof evts === "object") {
      console.log("type:", typeof evts);
      console.log(evts);
    }
  });
}

$('.trigger-weird').on('click', checkme);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="element-selector">howdy</div>
<input type="text" class="input-element-selector" />
<button class="trigger-weird">click me</button>
```

Comment: NOTE: reference the included link for older jQuery versions.